# How is inline assembler implemented in Linux and Windows compilers and ELF/EXE?

Tags: compiler-construction, inline-assembly, abi

Is the assembler already converted into the ABI binary in executables or is it done by OS?

Please can you give me link to GCC or any other compiler source code, which converts x86-64 inline asm into ABI binary.

Clarifications I don't know, if I know these right:

1. x86-64 ASCII instructions is converted 1:1 to binary blocks. Doesn't matter syntax
2. It is converted according to ABI specification

So I want to know if it is converted by compiler or by OS on executable proccessing.

Comment: gcc doesn't convert inline assembly to binary. It embeds pretty much literally (beyond substituting input/output operands and/or adding statements to set the inputs up / retrieve the outputs) what's in the `asm()` statement into the _assembly source file_ - which is then passed to the _actual_ assembler (from GNU binutils, normally). _That_ is where the object code generation happens.

Answer (score 1):

For `gcc`, the generation of an executable from e.g. C sourcecode is a multi-step process. One can observe that like:

```
$ gcc -v -save-temps -o t t.c -lm
Reading specs from ..../lib/gcc/..../specs
Configured with: ./configure [ .... ]
Thread model: posix
gcc version ....

 .../cc1 -E -quiet -v -iprefix ..../lib/gcc/..../ t.c ... -o t.i
[ output of the C preprocessor ... ]

..../gcc/.../libexec/gcc/..../cc1 -fpreprocessed t.i -quiet -dumpbase t.c ... -auxbase t -O8 -version -o t.s
[ output of the C compiler - which operates on the preprocessed source ... ]

.../binutils/.../bin/as -V -Qy -o t.o t.s
[ output of the GNU assembler - using the assembly created by the compiler ... ]

..../gcc/.../libexec/gcc/..../collect2 -rpath [ ... ] -L [ ... ] --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o t /usr/lib64/crt1.o /usr/lib64/crti.o ..../gcc/.../lib/gcc/.../crtbegin.o -L[ ... quite a few more ... ] t.o -lm -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed .../gcc/..../lib/gcc/..../crtend.o /usr/lib64/crtn.o
[ output by the linker - using the object file created by the assembler ... ]
```

And the result of the above, thanks to `-save-temps`, is that beyond your `t.c` sourcefile, you'll also find the intermediate stages:

- `t.i` which is the preprocessed C source (post the `cpp` / `cc1 -E` stage)
- `t.s` which is the assembly source (created by the C compiler)
- `t.o` which is the object (binary) code (created by the assembler)
- `t` which is the actual ELF executable (created by the linker)

*Inline assembly statements* are simply *embedded* by the C compiler into the assembly source it generates. If you say:

```
__asm__ __volatile__("scream loudly !\n");
```

then the result is:

```
t.s: Assembler messages:
t.s:147: Error: no such instruction: `scream loudly!'
```

because the compiler just ... doesn't care.

Comment: Only for detail I found it uses Small C compiler to handle this part.